# Python Selenium chrome driver .send_keys NoneType Error

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to enter a username into an input box but it is not working. The site opens and I can get it to click on the box, but not words show up. The chrome developer extensions warning popup appears. I'm still fairly new to programming. Any ideas? Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1478123673&rver=6.7.6631.0&wp=MBI&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fsecure%2fPassport.aspx%3frequrl%3dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.bing.com%252f%253fwlexpsignin%253d1&lc=1033&id=264960')
time.sleep(5)
usernameElem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('phholder').click()
usernameElem.send_keys('username')
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Matt/PycharmProjects/untitled/Bing.py", line 10, in <module>
usernameElem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong try using xpath or id:see below code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1478123673&rver=6.7.6631.0&wp=MBI&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fsecure%2fPassport.aspx%3frequrl%3dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.bing.com%252f%253fwlexpsignin%253d1&lc=1033&id=264960')
time.sleep(5)
usernameElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='i0116']")
#Either use above xpath or use id 
#usernameElem = browser.find_element_by_id("i0116")
usernameElem.send_keys('username')
```

Comment: The find_element_by_id worked. Thank you for your help, I was trying to figure this out for hours. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you should perform **send_keys** function to an element
So that first assign the element to the variable *usernameElem* and after that click it as a function, then you will be able to send kes to the *usernameElem* element

```
usernameElem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('phholder')
usernameElem.click()
usernameElem.send_keys('username')
```